# A/C blows hot air on acceleration

Tags: chevrolet, ac, malibu

2008 Malibu A/C blows hot air on acceleration. At idle or once maintained speed, it cools and blows cold again.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like normal behavior.  Under load, most cars will disengage the A/C compressor clutch to provide more power for acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXx21L6Kixw Your AirCon is turned off by the system when you accelerate to allow full power from the engine to accelerate the vehicle. The video link will show you how to clean the carbon tracks on the AirCon control knobs. The symptoms you describe could very well be caused by 'dirty' tracks. Further to this an AirCon service at your repair shop should find any problems such as a gas leak and low charge.